# How to change the wallpaper of a windows machine through a service (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, service

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Timers;

namespace WindowsServicesManager
{
    class WallpaperService
    {
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
        Int32 uAction,
        Int32 uParam,
        String lpvParam,
        Int32 fuWinIni);
        

        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        private Random rand = new();

        public WallpaperService()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100) {AutoReset = true};
            _timer.Elapsed += change;
        }

        void change(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetWallpaper($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/Icon.png");
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(rand.Next(6, 15)).TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        public void SetWallpaper(String path) => SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, path, 0x01 | 0x02);

        public void Start()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it as a console app it works perfectly, but as soon as I install it as a service it just doesn't work, everything is run on windows 10

Tried changing timers, paths of the image

Comment: Just for clarification, is this the whole code or are you calling the Start method from somewhere else in the windows service?

Comment: @Izanagi The start method is called properly with TopShelf, worked with every service before so not the issue

Comment: Have you checked the return of SystemParametersInfo? I assume it throws a Win32Exception of "This operation requires an interactive window station.". Services are non-interactive. They have no connection to a desktop. And/or if you let it run under the local system account that user never has a desktop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can have multiple users logged in at the same time so I'm not sure if it makes sense to put something like this in a service.

The wallpaper is a per-user setting. Is the service supposed to change the wallpaper for all users?

Services run in session 0 while users log into session 1 and higher. Even if you impersonate a user, you will not be able to broadcast the update message because of session/window station issues.

If you only want to update the wallpaper on boot and/or each time a user logs off, I suppose you could write directly to the HKEY_USERS key.

If you want to update dynamically based on a timer I suppose you could use `CreateProcessAsUser` to spawn a helper process with the users token in the correct session but this is a lot more work than just forgetting about being a service and just set your application to run at startup as a normal program instead...